# TextInputEditText endIconTint not applied when drawable set from code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I have a TextInputLayout defined with an endIconDrawable like this

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_24_black"
    app:endIconMode="custom">
```

The attributes explores shows `endIconTint=@color/design_icon_tint` as the default `empty` value.
It works alright and the default tint is applied correctly.
But if I change the drawable via the code like this

```
inputLayout.endIconDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_clear_24_black)
```

then the tint is no longer applied.

I know that it is possible to set some tint from the code like this

```
setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.my_tint_color))
```

but how do I set that `default` tint?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a bug IMO. It looks like there is an attempt to set the tint on the new drawable but there is some confusion about where the end icon image is stored.

Since there doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve the default tint, the easiest way I have found to reapply the default tint is as follows:

```
inputLayout.setEndIconMode(inputLayout.getEndIconMode());
```

(Java but easy enough to translate to Kotlin.) This does not change the icon mode but causes the tint to be reapplied.

---

**Update:** Unfortunately, the preceding clears the end icon click listener. If a click listener is involved then the following will work AND preserve the listener:

**MyTextInputLayout**

```
public class MyTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {
    private ColorStateList mMyEndIconTintList;

    public MyTextInputLayout(@NonNull @NotNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyTextInputLayout(@NonNull @NotNull Context context, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyTextInputLayout(@NonNull @NotNull Context context, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setEndIconTintList(@Nullable ColorStateList endIconTintList) {
        mMyEndIconTintList = endIconTintList;

        // Call with null then the tint list to bypass an efficiency check that determines if
        // the tint list has actually changed.
        if (mMyEndIconTintList != null) {
            super.setEndIconTintList(null);
        }
        super.setEndIconTintList(endIconTintList);
    }

    public ColorStateList getEndIconTintList() {
        return mMyEndIconTintList;
    }
}
```

The code sample is:

```
MyTextInputLayout inputLayout = findViewById(R.id.inputLayout);
inputLayout.setEndIconDrawable(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_clear_24_black));
inputLayout.setEndIconTintList(inputLayout.getEndIconTintList());
```

The layout will reference *MyTextInputLayout* instead of *TextInputLayout*.

The Kotlin version:

```
class MyTextInputLayout2 @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : TextInputLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    private var mMyEndIconTintList: ColorStateList? = null

    override fun setEndIconTintList(endIconTintList: ColorStateList?) {
        mMyEndIconTintList = endIconTintList

        // Call with null then the tint list to bypass an efficiency check that determines if
        // the tint list has actually changed.
        if (mMyEndIconTintList != null) {
            super.setEndIconTintList(null)
        }
        super.setEndIconTintList(endIconTintList)
    }

    fun getEndIconTintList(): ColorStateList? {
        return mMyEndIconTintList
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** If you just want to get the default value for the end icon's tint, the following code will fetch the applicable *ColorStateList* from the theme. The disadvantage of this method, compared to the others above, is that it will not produce override values for the tint of the end icon if the tint is defined in the layout XML or the style attribute for the view.

See comments in the code.

```
private void setEndIconTintFromTheme(Context context, TextInputLayout inputLayout) {
    // Force the tint to change. This, also, is probably a bug.
    inputLayout.setEndIconTintList(null);
    inputLayout.setEndIconTintList(getDefaultEndIconTint(context));
}

private ColorStateList getDefaultEndIconTint(Context context) {
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
    // textInputStyle controls styling for the TextInputLayout and is where endIconTint is
    // defined as @color/design_icon_tint
    theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.textInputStyle, typedValue, true);

    // We have the styles attribute. Now get the tint value.
    int[] attrs = {R.attr.endIconTint};
    TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, attrs);
    ColorStateList csl = ta.getColorStateList(0);
    ta.recycle();
    return csl;
}
```

Comment: It solves the tint issue but also resets onEndIconClick listener.

Comment: Wow! Fixing that small issue becomes too comlex.  But thanks anyway.

Comment: @yaugenka It extends the functionality of the underlying class, so it is a typical implementation. The Kotlin version is shorter. Maybe someone has an easier way.

Comment: Thanks @Cheticamp. I ended in just putting the color into the resoure list and applying it to the drawable for now. That's the simplest workaround until they get it fixed.